# Firestore security rules, get() and the allow create operation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've made an app where users can post records to the firestore database. I'm now at the point where I'm implementing security rules but I'm struggling to find a solution.

My code looks like this

```html
docRef.get().then(function(doc){
            if(doc.exists){
                docRef.set(//data to set here)
            } else {
                docRef.update(//data to update here)
            }
            .catch((error) => {
              alert('Error' + error);
            })
```

My rules are currently set to allow the user to create an object if they are authorised, and only allow an update if the user id on the record matches themselves.

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user}{
     allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
   allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.id;    
    }
    match /equipment/{document} {
     allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read, update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user;
    }
```

I think the problem lies in that I'm trying to get the object prior to creating it. However I need to perform these checks prior to writing to the document.
Am I right in thinking this the problem? and if so is there a solution I can implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on my rules, but I hope this helps.

If you're trying to make sure the user is editing something they own and their `uid` is the same as the `document id`....

```
function isOwner(userId) {
  return request.auth.uid == userId
}
match /users/{userId} { //this is the document 
    allow write: if isOwner(userId);
}
```

If you're trying to make sure they are the creator of a document:

```
match /equipment/{documentId} {
   allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
   allow read, update: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/equipment/documentId).data.userId == request.auth.uid;
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0

You need to use the get function to retrieve a document you're interested in. That function returns data that has the related fields you can compare to, in this case, whatever field name you stored the user ID on so you can compare it to their `auth.uid`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the 'create' rule as following:

```
allow create: if request.auth.uid != null &&
                 request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.id;
```

This is what documentation says: *"if your ruleset allows the pending write, the **request.resource** variable contains the future state of the document."*